# AWS ECR images not creating

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to deploy my containers to ECR by following some tutorials. (Please note, I'm totally new to the ECR flow).
My workflow on Github actions is successful however when I check my ECR repository no images have been built. Here is my deplo.yml file that contains the workflow

```
name: Deploy to prod

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
 

jobs:

  build:
    name: Build image
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Check out code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
    - name: Configure AWS credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: us-west-2

    - name: Login to Amazon ECR
      id: login-ecr
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

    - name: Build, tag, and push docker image to Amazon ECR
      env:
        REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        REPOSITORY: my_repository_name
        IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
      run:
        docker-compose build --file ./myservice_docker/docker-compose.yml --tag myservice-service:$(date +%s) .
        docker-compose push --file ./myservice_docker/docker-compose.yml --tag myservice-service:$(date +%s) .
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is the right command to push docker images to ECR.

Can you try below commands instead?

```
docker-compose build --tag myservice-service:$(date +%s) --file ./myservice_docker/docker-compose.yml .

docker tag myservice-service:$(date +%s) xxxxx.dkr.ecr.${region}.amazonaws.com/myservice-service:$(date +%s)

docker push xxxx.dkr.ecr.${region}.amazonaws.com/myservice-service:$(date +%s)
```